# Termcap tgetstr getting arrow keys

Tags: c, unix, tty, termcap

I'm trying to get the string representing the arrow key up from the termcap database. Using the following:

```
char *buffer = malloc(2048);
tgetent(buffer, getenv("TERM")); //TERM = xterm-256color
char *key_up = tgetstr("ku", &buffer); // gives me \EOA
```

> `ku` String of input sent by typing the up-arrow key.

The problem is the arrow key up is actually passed as `\E[A` when typing into the program. It's also passed like this to `cat`. I tried with different terminal emulators and shells and they all passed it the same way.

So I decided to hardcode this value for the key instead of using the `ku` value, and it works, but doesn't feel right.

Am I missing something here? How can I programmatically get the right `ku` value?

Comment: Seems that your TERM is set incorrectly?

Comment: I am using KDE + Konsole and my term is set to `xterm-256color` and *my* terminal does produce `\E[A`

Comment: ... and ku returns `\E0A`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal descriptions are written for *full-screen* applications, which are initialized using one or more terminal capabilities assigned to this.  About half of the terminal descriptions initialize the terminal's cursor- and keypad-keys to use *application mode*.  In application mode, those keys send different characters.

The ncurses FAQ [*My cursor keys do not work*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#cursor_appmode) goes into more detail.

If you are trying to use a terminal description for some non-screen command-line application, you could make your command-parser treat both *`\E[`* (CSI) and *`\EO`* (SS3) as the same thing, and ignore the difference between the two modes.  That was done in some configuration for `zsh`, as mentioned in the [xterm manual page](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Special-Keys).

By the way, if your "termcap" is actually an interface to a terminfo system (such as ncurses), it is not necessary to allocate the buffer, since that is ignored. ncurses' [manual](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_termcap.3x.html#h3-INITIALIZATION)  says:

> - The  emulation  ignores  the buffer pointer **`bp`**.  The *termcap* library would store a copy of the terminal description in the area
>     referenced  by this pointer.  However, *ncurses* stores its terminal descriptions in compiled binary form, which is not the  same
>     thing.